# Call PHP function with button onClick with parameter/ AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, function, parameters

Hello I want to call my function download when the user click on the button, basically:

```
<input type='button' name='Release' onclick="document.write('<?php downloadFichier($tab1, $t2) ?>');" value='Click to Release'>
```

Of course doesn't work, so I try to do with a AJAX, I don't know this language, but it is possible to do what I want: call my PHP function with 2 parameters?

```
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'file_product.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("p").text(data);
                }
            });
   });
});
</script>
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: **2 parameters** : what are the kind of your parameters ? Strings ? Objects ? Integers ?

Comment: You need to include jquery, did you?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: When you use jQuery there is never any need for inline JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call a js-function with onclick event like this:

```
<input type='button' name='Release' onclick="downloadFichier(param1, param2)" value='Click to Release'>
```

And your AJAX-function should be like this:

```
function downloadFichier(param1, param2){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'file_product.php',
            data: "param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2,
            success: function(data) {
                $("p").text(data);
            }
        });
```

You can get your params in PHP-script from the $_REQUEST array by their names (param1, param2).

Answer (score 1):

@PaulBasenko inspired this alternative, where you set the parameters through some `<input type="hidden" />` :

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="tab1" value="<?= $tab1 ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t2" value="<?= $t2 ?>" />
    <button type="submit">Click to Release</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() { // equivalent of "$(document).ready(function(){"
    $('body').on('submit', '#form1', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'file_product.php',
            data : formData,
            success : function(data) {
                $('#p').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PhP**

```
<?php
    $tab1 = (isset($_POST['tab1'])) ? $_POST['tab1'] : null;
    $t2 = (isset($_POST['t2'])) ? $_POST['t2'] : null;

    // process & return json_encoded data
?>
```

**How it works ?**

When clicking on the button, which is a `type="submit"`, it will trigger the `submit` event for its parent `form`. Then, jQuery listen to this event and immediately blocks it using `èvent.preventDefault()` in order to call Ajax instead of a regular synchronous call to a php file.