# PHP/AJAX shows every time information after submit

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<form id="myForm" name="gadaj"> <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/> 
<input type="submit" name="click" value="button"> </form> <p id="status"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         function info()
         {
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Message Sent";
     setTimeout(function() {
$('#status').fadeOut('slow');
   }, 1000);
         }
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'submit.php',
                data : $('#myForm').serialize(),

                   success: function (response){
  {
      document.forms['myForm'].reset();
      info();   
  }

                },
                     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus,errorThrown) {
 alert("Some Error.");
  }

            });

        });
    });
});

</script>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" name="gadaj">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
    <input type="submit" name="click" value="button" id="klik">

</form>

 <p id="status"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it's only one time shows Message Sent. It's kind of webchat txt field and I wanna show message text every time after sent. How do this ?
I do not know Ajax. I just found it but I do not how to do any change.

Comment: Instead of form submit, you could have tried button onclick

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
    <body>
    <form id="myForm" name="gadaj">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
        <input type="submit" name="click" value="button">

    </form>

     <p id="status"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
`

Comment: Anyone know how edit main post ?

Comment: give the button an ID and then use $("#id").click() instead of form.submit

Comment: I sent edit request. Please accept it

Comment: Santhosh can you give me some example ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716499/how-to-call-a-php-script-function-on-a-html-button-click

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223900/call-php-function-with-button-onclick-with-parameter-ajax

Comment: _“I do not know Ajax.”_ - then please make an effort to go read up on the basics of it. _“I just found it but I do not how to do any change.”_ - the purpose of this site is not to fix or modify stuff that you found somewhere for you.

Comment: Santhosh, click() function only refreshing file and add whitespaces do database only with massive numbers. This example shows only one time after click. How do that always will be message visible - after each submit button click

Comment: Where in code put it ? : $("#klik").click();

Comment: replace $("#myForm").submit(function(event){

Comment: with $("#klik").click(function(event){

Comment: Unfortunatelly not working. Still only one time shows message and I have to refresh (or F5) to see again message